# Inspect blocks created with by in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a simple way to inspect one of the blocks of data created when using 'by' in data.table?

For example if I am grouping iris by 'Species'

```
ir <- data.table(iris)
ir[, someFunction(), by = Species]
```

Inspecting one block is the equivalent of filtering

```
ir[Species == "setosa",]
```

I want to be able to see all variables to make sure the grouping is correct, however I don't to type lots of '==' statements when using multiple variables in 'by'

Comment: Your question is unclear. When and in what manner you wish to "inspect blocks"?

Comment: I'm imagining the data with the split, apply, combine analogy.  Using 'by' splits the data.table into blocks.  I want to inspect one of those blocks to make sure the grouping is correct

Comment: Maybe something like `ir[, lapply(.SD, head), by = Species]`?

Comment: That's a nice way to do it.  I used `ir[, lapply(.SD, head, n = 1L), by = Species]` to make it easy to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `browser()`.

```
ir[, (function (x) browser())(.SD), by = Species]
```

`x` will contain the data related to each Species or whatever is given in your `by` argument.

---

### EDIT

To include all columns:

```
ir[, (function (x) browser())(.SD), by = Species, .SDcols = names(ir)]
```

Comment: In this case I want to be able to see the categories as well. However, I didn't know you could do this - it's useful for lots of other things. Thank you

Comment: @EdG I see you probably are happy using `head()` but I updated my answer anyway to include the categories.

Comment: Both methods will be useful, but this gives me exactly what I wanted.  Using 'head' works if the number of the rows in the block isn't an issue